# jQuery drop down nav, some items not hiding on mouseout

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, delay, html-lists

I have a horizontal multi level drop down navigation using UL's that works fine if you hover over the items in a controlled manner, but as soon as you speed thing up by moving the mouse quicker - items either "stick" to the "show" status and don't hide again until you hover over them once more.

Also, when hovering between items, such as ul li to another level of ul li ul li the sub item disappears if you are out by one pixel when you move the mouse. This is technically what the script should do, but how do I add a small delay?

Here is my jquery:

```
$(function() {
$('ul.sub-menu').hide();
$('.sub-menu ul').hide();

$('#menu-navigation li').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').slideDown("fast");
    },
function(){
    $(this).children('ul').hide();
});

$('#menu-navigation ul li').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').slideDown("fast");
    },
function(){
    $(this).children('ul').hide();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function(){
  var element=this;
  Timeout( function(){
    $(element).find('>ul').fadeOut('slow')
    }, 2000 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shree, where exactly in my script would I put this code? I'm not sure I understand exactly what it does so therefore I'm not sure how I should implement it!